# Install program - how to open

Tags: software-installation

I am really new to Ubuntu (I have the 22.4 version) and I have to install a program called NeuroDebian (see here: [website](http://neuro.debian.net/)). I followed the instructions of the site, and pasted

```
wget -O- http://neuro.debian.net/lists/jammy.de-m.libre | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neurodebian.sources.list
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com 0xA5D32F012649A5A9
```

This seemed to work. After

```
sudo apt-get install neurodebian
```

and

```
sudo apt-get update
```

it showed me that it has been installed. However, I cannot open it. I thought simply the command `neurodebian` or `sudo neurodebian`will work, but it always tells me that the command is not found.

What is the problem? Or how should I open the program?

Comment: *"I thought simply the command neurodebrian or sudo deurodebrian will work"*. Are the spelling errors in your commands or did you only make the errors in your question? Please edit your question.

Comment: @Nmath Thank you for noticing, unfortunately/fortunately I did not make spelling errors in  the terminal, only in the post.

Comment: Add the output of `dpkg -L neurodebian` to the post, please